# Programming rev in sed

Tags: linux, sed

I'm trying to write an utility that reverses lines of input. The following just prints the lines as they are though:

```
#!/bin/sed -f
#insert newline at the beginning
s/^/\n/
#while the newline hasnt moved to the end of pattern space, rotate
: loop
/\n$/{!s/\(.*\)\(.$\)/\2\1/;!b loop}
#delete the newline
s/\n//
```

Any ideas on what's wrong?

Comment: See [here](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt) for a solution.

Comment: Was a challenge ? Why not using `tac` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/\n$/{!s/\(.*\)\(.$\)/\2\1/;!b loop}
```

- the `!` is after an address/range normaly
- the `!b` (*not than goto* if I understang your meaning) is maybe a `t` (if substitution occur, goto)
- `$` is not part of the last group but just after

so this line is:

```
/\n$/ !{s/\(.*\)\(.\)$/\2\1/;t loop}
```

now, this code just (in final) do nothing it add a new line at start and move it until the end by swapping last to first character and does not reveverse anything.

```
sed 'G
:loop
s/\(.\)\(\n.*\)/\2\1/
t loop
s/.//' YourFile
```

should do the trick

@TobySpeight still enhance the code removing the need of a 1st group (code adapted)

Comment: The substitution can be simplified, as the first term is redundant - `s/\(.\)\(\n.*\)/\2\1/`

Comment: right, i was starting from other side first so forget to reread. i adapt the solution with this

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

```
$ echo -e '123\n456\n789' |sed -nr '/\n/!G;s/(.)(.*\n)/&\2\1/;/^\n/!D;s/\n//p'
321
654
987
```

the core ideas:

1. we need a loop to deal with each line, and fortunately we can use `D` command can simulate a loop;
2. we need to loop over ONE line, which is difficult, because `sed` deals with  one line every time; but we can use `s` and `D` command to simulate a loop over one line.
3. how to avoid infinite loop? we need a `flag char` to identify the end of each line, `\n` is the perfect choice.
4. `D` command delete chars util first `\n` in the `pattern space` every time, 
   and then force `sed` jump to its first command, which is a loop actually! So we also need to add some useless `placeholder` to be deleted by `D` command before the final string, and we can just use contents in `current line` before `\n` (`\n` also included).

Explains:

1. `/\n/!G`: if current `pattern space` contain `\n`, which means this command is in a loop of dealing with one line; otherwise, use `G` command to append the `\n` and `hold space` to the `pattern space` (`sed` will delete `\n` of every line before putting it into `pattern space`), the content of `pattern space` after `G` command is the origin content and a `\n`.
2. `s/(.)(.*\n)/&\2\1/;`: use `s` command to delete the first char (util `\n`) and then insert it after the final string.
3. `/^\n/!D;s/\n//p`: if current `pattern space` starts with `\n`, which means this line has been resolved already, so use `s/\n//p` to delete the `flag char: \n` and print the final string; otherwise use `D` command to delete the `useless placeholder`, and then jump to the first command to deal with the second char...

To make a summary, the contents in `pattern space` in a loop are shown as the followings:

```
123\n [(1)(23\n)] =s=> 123\n23\n1 [(123\n)(23\n)(1)] =D=> 23\n1
23\n1 [(2)(3\n)1] =s=> 23\n3\n21 [(23\n)(3\n)(2)1] =D=> 3\n21
3\n21 [(3)(\n)21] =s=> 3\n\n321 [(3\n)(\n)(3)21] =D=> \n321
\n321 [()(\n)321] =s=> \n321 =!D=> \n321 =s-p=> 321
```

There are some derived solutions:

### Solution 2

#### the `placeholder` can be set another string ending with a `\n`:

```
$ echo -e '123\n456\n789' |sed -nr '/\n/!G;s/(.)(.*\n)/USELESS\n\2\1/;/^\n/!D;s/\n//p'
321
654
987
```

### Solution 3

#### Use a direct loop instead of obscure `D` command

```
$ echo -e '123\n456\n789' |sed -nr '/\n/!G;s/(.)(.*\n)/&\2\1/;Tend;D;:end;s/\n//p'
321
654
987
```

### Solution 4

#### Use `.` to fetch the first char `\n`

```
$ echo -e '123\n456\n789' |sed -nr '/\n/!G;s/(.)(.*\n)/&\2\1/;/^\n/!D;s/.//p'
321
654
987
```

### Solution 5

```
$ echo -e '123\n456\n789' |sed -nr ':loop;/\n/!G;s/(.)(.*\n)/\2\1/;tloop;s/.//p'
321
654
987
```

This solution is much easier to understand, the contents in `pattern space` res shown as the followings:

```
123\n [(1)(23\n)] =s=> 23\n1 [(23\n)(1)]
23\n1 [(2)(3\n)1] =s=> 3\n21 [(3\n)(2)1]
3\n21 [(3)(\n)21] =s=> \n321 [(\n)(3)21]
\n321 [()(\n)321] =s=> \n321 =s=> 321
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using the wrong tool for the job and trying to understand/use constructs that became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented.

```
$ cat file
tsuj
esu
na
etaorporppa
loot

$ awk -v FS= '{rev=""; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) rev = $i rev; print rev}' file
just
use
an
approproate
tool
```